# mapbox create, load, and edit attributes of mbtiles

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, tilemill, mbtiles, tilestache

This is not really a programming question but more of looking for advice. I am trying to figure out the best way to load about 15 million polygons onto a web map. The file is large, about 20GB uncompressed.

The best solution that I have found is to use .mbtiles format to turn the geojson data into vector tileset. I did this with a portion of the data using MapBox with Tippecanoe but they do have upload limits of 25GB, I would assume all 15 million polygons with attributes are going to be larger than that.

Also, it seems a little slow when I load a sample of the .mbtiles into mapbox. Is there a better and faster solution than using MapBox to host the tiles? I am looking for faster tile loading times.

I am also wondering once the .mbtiles tiles are generated is it possible to edit the attributes of each individual polygon and if so, how? It would seem like a huge pain to have to go back and edit my geojson data, convert to .mbtiles and upload every time. I appreciate any help with this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a lot of separate questions there:

> I would assume all 15 million polygons with attributes are going to be larger than [25GB, in mbtiles format]

I wouldn't assume that. You should try it.

> Is there a better and faster solution than using MapBox to host the tiles? I am looking for faster tile loading times.

I'd very surprised if Mapbox's hosting is your bottleneck. Or rendering with Mapbox-GL-JS for that matter. But other solutions include cloud.tilehosting.com, or self-hosting with something like Tessera.

> I am also wondering once the .mbtiles tiles are generated is it possible to edit the attributes of each individual polygon and if so, how?

You can use `tile-join`, in the same package as Tippecanoe. https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#tile-join

Comment: Thank you, Steve. Very helpful information. I have another question for you. The tile-join seems like it is going to be a lot of work since the information will need to be updated frequently. I am currently storing the attribute information in a DB on a server. I then join the json data from the DB with the vector tile geometries programmatically. This causes a great deal of slow down when having to fetch hundreds, thousands of polygons from the DB. Is there a more efficient way to doing this, outside of adding the attribute data directly to the tiles?

Comment: Possibly using [feature state](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-feature-state) would be more efficient. But maybe ask a separate question for that.